# Adding all opening and closing tags to the output using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, tags

Suppose I have an Xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<root xmlns:dbk="http://K.com"
    xmlns:dbs="http://S.com"
    xmlns:dbp="http://p.com"
    xmlns:dbm="http://z.com" >
   <a>
       This is the first text
       <alter>
             <dbk:x> Hello </dbk:x>
             <dbs:y role='Strong'>World </dbs:y>
      </alter>
  </a>
  <d>
      This is the second text
      <alter>
            <dbp:w> How are </dbp:w>
            <dbm:z role='Italic'>  you? </dbm:z>
      </alter>
  </d>
</root>
```

I want to capture all alter elements however everything should be printed out including opening and closing tags as well as attributes so the output should be like this:

```
<x> Hello </x>
<y role='Strong'>  World </y> 
<w> How are </w>
<z role='Italic'>  you? </z>
```

Note that

1. I want to output all tags ( **both opening and closing tags** and **attributes**) within the alter element as well as the text
2. The tags can be varied and the decision should **NOT** be based on the name of the tag as they are all auto-generated and dynamic
3. The tag name within one alter element can be different from the tags added to another alter element like above :

The first alter has

```
<x></x>
```

and

```
<y role=''></y>
```

while the second alter has

```
  <w></w>
```

and

```
  <z role=''><z>
```

And the third alter can have something else and ….

Not sure what the XSLT should look like?

**Edited:**

Based on @Mads Hansen’s solution , the output would be :

```
<dbk:x xmlns:dbk="http://K.com" xmlns:dbs="http://S.com" xmlns:dbp="http://p.com"     xmlns:dbm="http://z.com"> Hello </dbk:x>
<dbs:y role="Strong" xmlns:dbs="http://S.com" xmlns:dbk="http://K.com" xmlns:dbp="http://p.com" xmlns:dbm="http://z.com">World </dbs:y>
<dbp:w xmlns:dbp="http://p.com" xmlns:dbk="http://K.com" xmlns:dbs="http://S.com" xmlns:dbm="http://z.com"> How are </dbp:w>
<dbm:z role="Italic" xmlns:dbm="http://z.com" xmlns:dbk="http://K.com" xmlns:dbs="http://S.com" xmlns:dbp="http://p.com">  you? </dbm:z>
```

The problem is that all namespaces have been added to outport as well which is not desired.

Is there any way to get rid of all namespaces?

Comment: The requested output (as well as the output you are getting now) is not valid XML: you must have a root element.

Comment: The output should have all tags however , it is not supposed to be an XML output ( i.e. an XML file ) so there is no need to have root tag as well as  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Then perhaps you should output this as *text*, following some predefined pattern - and not care about opening and closing tags. The problem with outputting XML without a root is that some processors will put it all on one line. What is the overall purpose of this exercise?

Comment: It would also help knowing if the hierarchy is indeed fixed (as assumed by Mads Hansen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::alter/*"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will produce this result:

```
<output>
   <x> Hello </x>
   <y role="Strong">World </y>
   <w> How are </w>
   <z role="Italic">  you? </z>
</output>
```

Removing the `<output>` tags from the first template will result in invalid XML, which some processors (e.g. libxslt) may render as:

```
<x> Hello </x><y role="Strong">World </y><w> How are </w><z role="Italic">  you? </z>
```